# Java streams: Optional to stream

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

This is my code:

```
Optional<Application> application = this.applicationDao.findById(id);
```

where, `Application` class is:

```
public class Application {
    private String code;    
    private Collection<ApplicationQuote> quotes;
}
```

I need to create an stream from return `Optional<Application>` like this:

```
(app, quote-1) > (app, quote-2) > ... > (app, quote-n)
```

Where each `quote-n` is inside returned `Optional<Application>.quotes`.

I hope I've explained so well.

Up to now, I've been able to write this code, but I don't feel confortable with that:

```
Optional<Application> application = this.applicationDao.findById(id);
    application.map(app -> Pair.of(app, Optional.ofNullable(app.getQuotes())))
        .filter(quote -> quote.getValue().isPresent())
        .map(quote -> quote.getValue().get().stream().map(q -> Pair.of(quote.getKey(), q)));
```

Comment: what do you mean by "but I don't feel confortable with that:" ?

Comment: What are the parts you're not comfortable with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`Optional.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T))

Ideally what you currently have is **`Optional<Stream<Pair<Application, ApplicationQuote>>> optionalPairStream`** and what you might just be looking for just add a default case and get just the `Stream` as :

```
Stream<Pair<Application, ApplicationQuote>> pairStream = application
        .map(app -> Pair.of(app, Optional.ofNullable(app.getQuotes())))
        .filter(quote -> quote.getValue().isPresent())
        .map(quote -> quote.getValue().get().stream().map(q -> Pair.of(quote.getKey(), q)))
        .orElse(Stream.empty());
```

#### [`Optional.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream())

With Java9, you can update the same code as:

```
Stream<Pair<Application, ApplicationQuote>> pairStream = application
           .map(app -> Pair.of(app, Optional.ofNullable(app.getQuotes())))
           .filter(quote -> quote.getValue().isPresent())
           .stream() // new API
           .flatMap(quote -> quote.getValue().orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                   .stream().map(q -> Pair.of(quote.getKey(), q)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplication things here. i.e you don't actually need to wrap `app.quotes` into an optional only to check if it's non-null (which actually abuses the main purpose of Optional) etc...

since you want a `Stream<Pair<Application, ApplicationQuote>>` you can do so as follows:

JDK8:

```
application.filter(app -> app.getQuotes() != null)
           .map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
           .flatMap(app -> app.getQuotes().stream().map(quote -> Pair.of(app, quote)));
```

JDK9:

```
application.filter(app -> app.getQuotes() != null).stream()
           .flatMap(app -> app.getQuotes().stream().map(quote -> Pair.of(app, quote)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Optional<Pair<String,List<String>> quotesForApp = 
     app.map(a -> a.getQuotes()
                     .stream()
                     .map(Quote::getValue())
                     .collect(toList()) // optional list of quotes now
        // we can call app.getCode() safely, or we wouldn't be mapping
        .map(quotes -> Pair.of(app.getCode(), quotes));
```